# Футер съезжает

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь поставить отступы (`padding`) в диве футер, чтобы текст не прижимался, но двигается не текст в футере, а сам див. Почему так происходит?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>проба</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header1"></div><br><br>
<div id="glav"><a href="index.html">главная</a></div><br>
<div id="menu"><a href="menu.html">содержание</a></div><br>
<div id="ist"><a href="ist.html">источник</a></div><br>
<div id="content">
<h3 align="center">О районе</h3><br>
  <p>Кугарчинский район образован 20 августа 1930 года. Он расположен на юге республики Башкортостан и граничит с Мелеузовским, Куюргазинским, Зианчуринским, Зилаирским, Бурзянским районами и Тюльганским районом Оренбургской области. Его территория 3371 кв. км. Население на 1 января 2006 года составило 33531 человек, из них башкир 56%, русских 31%, татар 10%, и других -3%.</p>
<p>Районный центр - с. Мраково с населением 8154 человека, второй по величине населенный пункт - с. Юмагузино с населением 5277 человек.</p>
<p>Большая часть территории района отнесена к горно-лесной зоне Зилаирского плато. Район впечатляет экзотическими каньонами и пещерными красотами Мурадымовского ущелья, вольными лугами и чистыми реками, первозданными лесами и прекрасными березовыми рощами. Климат теплый, засушливый, отмечаются суховеи.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">© 2011</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

И стили:

```
body{
    background:#CFF;
    width:auto;
    padding-left:50%;
    margin:0;   
}                             
#main{
width:850px;
border:10px groove #99F ;
background:#FEFEFE;
margin-left:-425px;
}
#header1{
background-image: url(images/header1.jpg);
width:850px;
height:128px;                                                      
background-repeat:no-repeat;             
}
#glav{
float:left;
width:auto;
margin-left:20px;
font:italic 18px bolder Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     
}

#menu{
float:left;
width:auto;
clear:left;
margin-left:20px;
font:italic 18px bolder Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#ist{
float:left;
width:auto;
clear:left;
margin-left:20px;
font:italic 18px bolder Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#content{
width:auto;
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:50px;
text-align: justify;
}
p{
  text-indent:2em;
}
#footer{
    background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
    width:850px;
    height:30px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top:500px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:5px ;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая ширина элемента суммируется из заданной ширины и его внутреннего отступа. Так как ширина чётко задана (850) и есть отступ (5) - общая ширина элемента = 855 (вместо нужных 850). Для решения подобных проблем, не указывайте ширину элемента и поставьте свойство display: block; (для не блочных элементов), тогда общая ширина элемента будет всегда 100% ширины родителя.

```
#footer{
    background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
    height:30px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top:500px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:5px ;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А как ставите отступы? `margin` или `padding`?

`margin` двигает сам элемент, а `padding` - его содержимое

Comment: Paddig в том то и дело

Comment: А можно код(html+css)?

Comment: Думаю, что виноват `width:850px`, попробуйте его уменьшить на значение сдвигаемое в `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

Надо сделать padding: 1px;
Судя по всему, ваша проблема называется [margin-collapse.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

UPD: padding увеличивает соответствующее измерение. В вашем случае, рекомендую уменьшить высоту на соответствующее число пикселей.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer{
    background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
    width:845px;
    height:30px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top:500px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:5px ;
    clear:both;
}
```